# Spring data jdbc one-to-many wrong join

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I'm using spring-boot 2.3.3 and spring-data-jdbc 2.0.3 to model a relationship between to elements guitar and classType. A guitar has a classType.

My schema in H2 (also in MySQL) is this:

```
CREATE TABLE class_type (
    id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    description varchar(50) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE guitars (
    id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    classType bigint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (name),
    FOREIGN KEY (classType) references class_type(id)
);
```

And I have these classes:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(value = "guitars")
public class Guitar {
    @Id
    long id;
    String name;
    String description;
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "id")
    @Column(value = "classType")
    ClassType classType;
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(value = "class_type")
public class ClassType {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String description;    
}
```

My repository is like this:

```
@Repository
public interface GuitarRepository extends CrudRepository<Guitar, Long>, PagingAndSortingRepository<Guitar, Long> {}
```

When I invoke this test:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class GuitarOneManyTest {

    @Autowired
    GuitarRepository guitarRepository;

    @Test
    void findAllByName() {
        System.out.println(guitarRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

This sentence appears with an incorrect LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT `guitars`.`id` AS `id`, `guitars`.`name` AS `name`, `guitars`.`description` AS `description`, `classType`.`id` AS `classType_id`, `classType`.`description` AS `classType_description` FROM `guitars` LEFT OUTER JOIN `class_type` AS `classType` ON `classType`.`id` = `guitars`.`id`
```

But I want the select to be like this:

```
SELECT (...) FROM `guitars` LEFT OUTER JOIN `class_type` AS `classType` ON `classType`.`id` = `guitars`.`classType`
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a one-to-many relationship. One `Guitar` would reference multiple `ClassType` instances.

Instead it seems to be intended as a many-to-one relationship: Many `Guitar` instances might reference the same `ClassType`. This makes `ClassType` a different aggregate from `Guitar` and therefore it must not be referenced by a direct java reference, but only by it's id.

See [Spring Data JDBC, References, and Aggregates](https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates) for a more detailed explanation how to model such a relationship with Spring Data JDBC.